# What does the - mean in this syslog configuration

Tags: linux, syslogd

```
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice
```

So the docs indicate:

*The various possible actions are:*

- *add the message to a file (example: /var/log/messages);*
- *send the message to a remote syslog server (example: @log.falcot.com);*
- *send the message to an existing named pipe (example: |/dev/xconsole);*
- *send the message to one or more users, if they are logged in (example:root,rhertzog);*
- *send the message to all logged in users (example: *);*
- *write the message in a text console (example: /dev/tty8).*

But doesn't mention anything about the prefixed -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html:

> You may prefix each entry with the minus "-'' sign to omit syncing the file after every logging.